# Can Chanting the Lalita saharanama actually grant any benefits when it's interpolated?

Tags: worship, devi, nama-japa, lalita, lalita-sahasranama

I have seen several 'anecdotal' sources on the internet [that claim that the The Lalita sahasranama popularly attrituted to the Lalitamahatmya of the  Brahmanda purana grants material and spiritual benefits to the practitioner when chanted](https://srilalithatripurasundari.wordpress.com/home/lalita-sahasranama/impact-of-chanting-lalitha-sahasranama/).

However, When I did  some personal research on the Brahmanda purana, it turned out that The Entire Lalita Mahatmya which is popularly attributed to the Brahmanda Purana itself is  a later day accretion/interpolation!

[image]

[image]

As Shown above, there are multiple signs that the Lalita mahatmya is A LATER INTERPOLATION and not a part of the Original Brahmandapurana.

1. [Original Brahmandapurana Concludes with the 4th chapter of the Upasamhara pada that lies just before the Lalita mahatmya.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc362937.html)
2. Lalita Mahatmya Begins with a fresh mangalacharana.
3. [Naarada Purana, While recounting the Contents of Brahmanda purana, Does not even mention Lalita mahatmya at all](https://www.getwisdom.in/index.php?flg=N&pmd=W&mdi=L&thm=2&vip=puran%20eng&puran=6%20Narad&sec=4&chap=19&pn=1422&act=back&cod=narad&bn1=chap&bn=page).
4. The Javanese Manuscript of the Brahmandapurana Too makes no mention of Lalita Mahatmya.

This means This Lalita mahatmya is not a bonafide work of Vyasa or Any Rishi. Which makes everything from the stories of Devi Lalita fighting Bhandasura to the thousand Names of Goddess Lalita to be completely fictional since it's the work of some later day author, and not that of any sage.

My Question Is really it possible for anyone to actually get any benefits, be it material or spiritual while chanting a completely fictional work like this? Are the claims of the Sahasranama granting material or spiritual benifits just a hoax or an exaggeration or Is there any element of truth to them?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151794/discussion-on-question-by-user33908-can-chanting-the-lalita-saharanama-actually); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

- one should understand what is **mantra**, how to use it correctly so that it helps you in your life.
- what is Mantra ? Mantra are the abstract text which contains very useful information/knowledge which has been given by our ancient people.
- purpose of mantras ? one should first has to learn to chant the mantras fluently even though without knowing its meanings. that mantra shall have solutions to many problems in your life, which you might have not come across those problems yet. As soon as start facing the problem, your sub-conscious mind will look at bits and pieces of the text in mantras and tries to research itself without your conscious effort. slowly it encourages you to know its inner meaning and go in search of elaborate details (opposite of abstraction) in scriptures, gurus or anywhere in the world. Then certainly you are set in right direction to solve the problem.
- example ? For childrens/kids if you teach mantra like 'taitriyya upanishad mantras' etc. later in their youth if they want to be a good student and seek good teacher and in case they knew mantra, it is very easy to know what qualities needed for better knowledge in better way. Else they end up searching the right way itself.
- hope this answer helps you.